# Passing arguments with special characters to batch script while delayedexpansion enabled

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line-arguments, delayedvariableexpansion

I need to call a script which accepts password as one of its arguments. Whenever the password contains `,` it is treated as a delimiter and the password will be split into two arguments and when it contains `!` all the special characters are omitted. I have tried enclosing them in  `'`, `"` and preprocessing the password to escape with both `^` and `^^`. Unfortunately, nothing worked. How to preserve these special characters in the password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, delayed expansion has to be turned of (temporarily) for that to work properly. The `!` has to be escaped (for the delayed part later) and quoting takes care of the rest:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM --- get parameter ---
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
set "x=%~1"
endlocal & set "x=%x:!=^!%"
REM --- end get param ---

set x
echo "!x!"
```

Output:

```
C:\TEST>test.bat "pass,!<& %|>word"
x=pass,!<& %|>word
"pass,!<& %|>word"
```

The main trick is the line `endlocal & set "x=%x:!=^!%"`. The `set` command is still *parsed* without delayed expansion, but *executed* after `endlocal` (as the whole line is parsed before anything gets executed - yes, strange thing...)

Comment: @aschipfl yes and no - depends on where it is (they are) in relation to other poison chars. (I think I remember a bulletproof method (by dbenham, I think), but can't find it right now - as far as I remember that was far more code though)

Comment: I guess it makes use of the built-in variable `CmdCmdLine`, which can be accessed with delayed expansion, but then you'd have to do the argument separation on your own...

Comment: @aschipfl oh, and `^` is another troublesome candidate.

Comment: Ah, because of delayed expansion, I think?

Comment: @aschipfl that's only half the truth. Also `set` treats it as an escape char and suppresses it.