# How to escape ASCII code in msbuild script?

Tags: msbuild

Msbuild uses ASCII code to escape special characters. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-special-characters?view=vs-2022

How to escape ASCII code?
I have environment variable **PWD** equal to **a%80b** and following msbuild script:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="NetUse">
    <Target Name="NetUse">
        <Exec Command='net use \\location /user:the_user "$(PWD)"'/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

If I run it, it shows  **net use \\location /user:the_user "a?b"** ... obviously the **%80** is considered as special character. How could I modify msbuild script, so it calls net **net use \\location /user:the_user "a%80b"** ?

Comment: Try using `"$([MSBuild]::Escape($(PWD)))"` and see if it works.

Comment: No change, @JonathanDodds . It's still a?b.

Comment: ... so far I figured out to fix the issue outside of msbuild script: before I run msbuild, I prepare escaped version of password: `PWD_ESCAPED = PWD.replaceAll('%','%25%25')` . Not as good as I hoped for (to do the work inside of msbuild script), but it helped me to move forward.

Comment: As I'm sure you are aware, having a password as an environment variable is a security vulnerability but I can imagine that this is a short term stopgap during development.

Comment: In fact it's a build environment managed by a Jenkins. The credentials are passed to the build script through process -level environment variable. I see it as a quite safe solution.

Comment: ah - because the process with the environment variable is transient. I understand.

Comment: I have a solution. Environment variables are mapped to properties but the value of the property will be 'unescaped' when used and the `%` interpreted as the prefix of a hex code. So, you need a way to read the environment variable without hex code interpretation: `$([System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PWD'))`

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are available in MSBuild as properties. The `PWD` environment variable is available as the `$(PWD)` property.

When a property is used, the hex code sequences will be interpreted. The value `a%80b` will be `a?b`. There isn't a way to 'turn off' the un-escaping. You could encode the `%`. The value `a%2580b` will become `a%80b`.

But a perhaps better way is to retrieve the value of the environment variable directly and not via the property. `System.Environment::GetEnvironmentVariable` is available as a [property function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2022).

A revised version of the code might be:

```xml
<Exec Command='net use \\location /user:the_user "$([System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PWD'))"'/>
```

Comment: It moves me forward, but there are 2 things: A) there are inner ' quotes in your command. It should be `<Exec Command='echo \\location /user:the_user &quot;$([System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("aPwd"))&quot;'/>` . B) as it's visible in my echo variation, the exec requires additional change (% should be doubled). Otherwise net use receives "a0b".

Comment: I copied your code in the question. That's where the quotes came from. I edited my example code.

Comment: The `Exec` tasks always runs `cmd`. `%8` is being interpreted by the command shell as an argument placeholder. See [Passing arguments with special characters to batch script while delayedexpansion enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61358483/passing-arguments-with-special-characters-to-batch-script-while-delayedexpansion)